# Serve video files with PHP for streaming that are located outside the document root

Tags: php, webserver, document-root

I am programming a file explorer/uploader of sorts that allows the user to preview images and video files without having to download the file to their hard drive. For privacy and security reasons, I am saving those asset files outside the document root. I am able to generate image previews by utilizing the GD library, however, I am unsure how I would serve a flash player say a SWF or FLV file for playback. Is there a way that PHP can serve up a temporary file via [readfile()](https://www.php.net/readfile)?

It would work something like this: `http://example.com/flv_serve.php?file=sample.flv`. readfile would then grab `$_GET['file']` from the asset directory and dump the file to the webserver as a FLV. Of course, it would first verify that the person accessing flv_serve.php has the rights to the file by the session.

Has anyone have to deal with a similar problem before?

Comment: Did GregPK's answer work for you?  If not how did you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the streaming, but if you want to just output the file I would just do:

```
// authentication
header("Content-type: application/x-shockwave-flash");
readfile($filePath);
```

I think that this would stream a normal resource (image, text, etc.), but am not sure on whether this will work with Flash and whether of not it is dependent on the player.

I did something like this and I'm sure it did stream well, but am not sure as to whether some other black magic was done to get the streaming capabilities (it was a pretty large project).

**Bottom line:** If you can pass the file on the webserver and it stream in the player, it will work just as well.